# "debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address" when trying to connect through SSH

Tags: ssh, permissions, tty

I am trying to connect to my server using

```
ssh user@server.com -vv
```

I get

```
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
```

error or just

```
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

when I do not use the `-vv` option.

`/dev/tty` file *does exist*. I am logged in as root, so I have access to it. `tty` command returns

```
/dev/console
```

I am remotely connected (using Putty) to the server, and I am trying to connect to that from another server. It is **not** a cron job. How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Does the /dev/tty device exist on both servers:

Comment: @derchris: Yes, it does exist. I can easily connect to `server.com` machine from other places.

Comment: What would be a main difference between a server you can, and the server you can't connect? Just trying to rule out any OS/version issues.

Comment: @derchris: I believe this is related to problem with `/dev/tty` on machine, that I am trying to ssh from, but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: I understand the problem. What I was asking was you said you can connect from somewhere else. So what is the difference between these 2 systems you try to connect from.

Comment: I can connect from real computer with Windows in Poland, can't connect from virtual server hosted somewhere in Ireland using Linux. But this is not issue here, because I logged in to `server.com` from many different machines.

Comment: Well, there is. You mentioned virtual server. It depends on which virtualization you use for this server. Some have limitations on console access, which /dev/tty is.

Comment: @derchris: Hmm, thanks for explaining. How can I check if I have limitations and how to overcome them with ssh?

Comment: What virtualization you are using?

Comment: Did you take a look at ssh server log (`/var/log/secure` on CentOS) to see what happen when you try to connect?

Answer (score 8):

What does `ls -la /dev/tty` show? Is it both world-readable and world-writeable?

> $ ls -la /dev/tty
>
> crw-rw-rw- 1 root tty 5, 0 Aug 23 20:58 /dev/tty
>
> $

That is what you should see. If not, that's your problem.

Comment: mu /dev/tty was strangely with the "crw-------" rights. Changing to crw-rw-rw- fixed the thing. This is the first time I had to do that in my ubuntu installations. Why were the rights not the good ones ?

Comment: Use `chmod 666 /dev/tty` to change to `rw-rw-rw-` rights.

Answer (score 2):

I had this `read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty` error when my private key was wrongly formatted - instead of many lines, it was passed as a one-liner, and you might have any other format issue like a forgotten "-" at the start or end, or something wrong at the end of the lines, like a missing newline format or an additional letter at the end of a line.

See [Dockerfile: clone repo with passwordless private key. Errors: “authentication agent” or “read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty”](https://superuser.com/questions/1633085/dockerfile-clone-repo-with-passwordless-private-key-errors-authentication-ag) for more details, with the main idea from [Add private key to ssh-agent in docker file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56400527/11154841), which again had the idea from [Gitlab CI/Docker: ssh-add keeps asking for passphrase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22829291/nohup-causes-read-passphrase-cant-open-dev-tty/66647740#66647740).

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me on a Docker image running `node:11-alpine` was to modify the SSH config, stripping password auth

```
echo 'PasswordAuthentication no' >> /etc/ssh/ssh_config
```

You should also be able to do it on a per-command basis via the `-o` flag, eg

```
ssh -o 'PasswordAuthentication no'
```

The problem is other commands need to know about it, for example `git`, in which case you could set the `$GIT_SSH` environment variable (something like this)

```
export GIT_SSH="ssh -o 'PasswordAuthentication no'"
```

The first option seemed the most pragmatic for my case, setting the flag by default across the entire system.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to add the following to `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
KbdInteractiveAuthentication yes
PermitTTY yes
```

Then restart ssh.